# How to pass objects in powershell

Tags: powershell

I can pass one object in powershell, but when I have 2 objects, only 1 is passed, the other is null.

psuedo-code:

```
function do-something($param1, $param2) {
...
}


do-something($a, $b)
```

Do I need to do something special to get both args passed to do-something?  What I have resorted to is using globals which I think will lead to other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although PowerShell allows for a "C#-style" function definition syntax (like in your example), the syntax for *invoking functions* is a little bit different - in that parameter arguments are **separated by whitespace rather than comma**, and optionally **passed by name**.

For what you're trying to do, either of these will work:

```
Do-Something $a $b
Do-Something -param1 $a -param2 $b
Do-Something -param1:$a -param2:$b
```

What your current code resolves to is:

```
Do-Something -param1 ($a, $b)
```

... which is why you only receive a single argument in the function.

See the [`about_Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7#functions-with-parameters) help file for further details

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  Being new to powershell, the syntax is a little bit different than what I'm used to.  This was very useful.  I'll have another go at about Functions, I thought I could call it the way I was used to doing.

Comment: Yeah, the PowerShell learning curve is a bit weird, but practice makes a master :) Be sure to check out the `about_Functions_Advanced*` topics as well - the syntax you're currently using is great for many general-purpose functions, but advanced functions allow a greater deal of control over input binding and the likes